# XSD To permit an element in two places

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I'm trying to allow `OUTPUTFORMAT` both before or after the `xsd:choice`.  I've tried using `xsd:all` instead of `xsd:sequence` but when I do that, I get an error do the the `maxOccurs="300"` on the `IMAGE` element.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
    <xsd:complexType name="IMDType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="VERSION" type="versionType"/>
            <xsd:element name="GENERATIONTIME" type="dateTimeType"/>
            <xsd:element name="PRODUCTORDERID" type="productOrderIdType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="PRODUCTCATALOGID" type="catIdOrNoneType"/>
            <xsd:element name="CHILDCATALOGID" type="catIdOrNoneType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="IMAGEDESCRIPTOR" type="imageDescriptorType"/>
            <xsd:element name="PRODUCTSCALE" type="productScaleType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="PRODUCTACCURACY" type="productAccuracyType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="RMSE2D" type="floatType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="BANDID" type="bandIdType"/>
            <xsd:element name="PANSHARPENALGORITHM" type="panSharpenAlgorithmType"/>
            <xsd:element name="NUMROWS" type="longType"/>
            <xsd:element name="NUMCOLUMNS" type="longType"/>
            <xsd:element name="PRODUCTLEVEL" type="productLevelType"/>
            <xsd:element name="PRODUCTTYPE" type="productTypeType"/>
            <xsd:element name="NUMBEROFLOOKS" type="intType"/>
            <xsd:element name="RADIOMETRICLEVEL" type="radiometricLevelType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="RADIOMETRICENHANCEMENT" type="radiometricEnhancementType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="BITSPERPIXEL" type="intType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="RESTRICTEDAREAINTERSECT" type="restrictedAreaIntersectType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="COMPRESSIONTYPE" type="compressionType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="JPEGPROFILENAME" type="jpegProfileNameType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:choice maxOccurs="8">
                <xsd:element name="BAND_B" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_C" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_G" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_N" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_N2" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_P" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_R" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_RE" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_S1" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_S2" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_S3" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_S4" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_S5" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_S6" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_S7" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_S8" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BAND_Y" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="WV03_SWIR" type="imdBandType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="OUTPUTFORMAT" type="ouputFormatType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="IMAGE" type="imdImageListType" maxOccurs="300"/>
            <xsd:element name="MAP_PROJECTED_PRODUCT" type="imdMapProjProdType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the choice by a model group G, then you can write the content model as ((OUTPUTFORMAT?, G?) | (G, OUTPUTFORMAT?)

```
choice
  sequence
    OUTPUTFORMAT minOccurs=0
    G minOccurs=0
  sequence
    G
    OUTPUTFORMAT minOccurs=0
```

But such devices get more and more convoluted and in the end, it's not clear what you're achieving - the rules as to what is and what isn't allowed become more and more difficult for anyone to understand. You really want to make a decision: either be completely flexible about ordering, or be completely strict about it.

Incidentally a clause like maxOccurs=300 can lead to very poor performance on some schema processors. Do you really have a good reason to set this limit?

Comment: what do you mean a model group G?

Comment: I tried this, but now it's complaining that I have OUTPUTFORMAT twice...

choice
  sequence
    OUTPUTFORMAT
    choice
  sequence
    OUTPUTFORMAT
    choice

Comment: By model group I mean an xs:group element, which avoids duplicating the entire xs:choice. You're allowed to have the same element more than once provided you avoid violating any of the constraints: so you need to show us exactly what you did and exactly what the error message was. Best done as a new question.